# Problem on type-conversion with string in int and float

Tags: c#, string, type-conversion

I am a beginer in monodevelop and i try to make a simple calculator but I have a problem with the equal button which do the type-conversion.
So my I have a problem on type-conversion.

I have 2 variables that contain the string of the 2 parts of my equation and I want to convert them into fuction of the type (int or float)
I tried to print the different variables but I was unsuccessful in doing so.

```
using System;
using Gtk;

public partial class MainWindow : Gtk.Window
{
    private string operationSigne;
    private string membre1;
    private string membre2;

    public MainWindow() : base(Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel) => Build();

    protected void OnDeleteEvent(object sender, DeleteEventArgs a)
    {
        Application.Quit();
        a.RetVal = true;
    }

    protected void OnBtnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        entry1.Text = entry1.Text + "0";
    }

    protected void OnBtnPtClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!entry1.Text.Contains("."))
        {
            entry1.Text = entry1.Text + ".";
        }
    }

    protected void OnBtnEgaleClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.membre2 = entry1.Text;
        if (this.operationSigne.Equals("+"))
        {
            if (this.membre1.Contains(".") || this.membre2.Contains("."))
            {
                entry1.Text = (float.Parse(this.membre1) + float.Parse(this.membre2)).ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                entry1.Text = (int.Parse(this.membre1) + int.Parse(this.membre2)).ToString();
            }
        }
        else if (this.operationSigne.Equals("-"))
        {
            if (this.membre1.Contains(".") || this.membre2.Contains("."))
            {
                entry1.Text = (float.Parse(this.membre1) - float.Parse(this.membre2)).ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                entry1.Text = (int.Parse(this.membre1) - int.Parse(this.membre2)).ToString();
            }
        }
        else if (this.operationSigne.Equals("/"))
        {
            if (this.membre1.Contains(".") || this.membre2.Contains("."))
            {
                entry1.Text = (float.Parse(this.membre1) / float.Parse(this.membre2)).ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                entry1.Text = (int.Parse(this.membre1) / int.Parse(this.membre2)).ToString();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (this.membre1.Contains(".") || this.membre2.Contains("."))
            {
                entry1.Text = (float.Parse(this.membre1) * float.Parse(this.membre2)).ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                entry1.Text = (int.Parse(this.membre1) * int.Parse(this.membre2)).ToString();
            }
        }
    }


    protected void OnBtnPlusClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.membre1 = entry1.Text;
        this.operationSigne = "+";
        entry1.Text = "";
    }

    protected void OnBtn3Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        entry1.Text = entry1.Text + "3";
    }

    protected void OnBtn2Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        entry1.Text = entry1.Text + "2";
    }

    protected void OnBtn1Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        entry1.Text = entry1.Text + "1";
    }

    protected void OnBtn4Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        entry1.Text = entry1.Text + "4";
    }

    protected void OnBtn5Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        entry1.Text = entry1.Text + "5";
    }

    protected void OnBtn6Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        entry1.Text = entry1.Text + "6";
    }

    protected void OnBtnFoisClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.membre1 = entry1.Text;
        this.operationSigne = "x";
        entry1.Text = "";
    }

    protected void OnBtnDivClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.membre1 = entry1.Text;
        this.operationSigne = "/";
        entry1.Text = "";
    }

    protected void OnBtn9Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        entry1.Text = entry1.Text + "9";
    }

    protected void OnBtn8Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        entry1.Text = entry1.Text + "8";
    }

    protected void OnBtn7Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        entry1.Text = entry1.Text + "7";
    }

    protected void OnBtnCClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void OnBtnViderClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        entry1.Text = "";
        this.membre1 = "";
        this.membre2 = "";
    }

    protected void OnButtonMoinsClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.membre1 = entry1.Text;
        this.operationSigne = "-";
        entry1.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Here is all my code, the problem comes from the function OnBtnEgaleClicked, I think.

I want that the opération works with a int and a float, 2 floats or two int.
Actualy, 2 int works but not the others, the app crashs.

Comment: can you provide some sample data?

Comment: for example when I write 1+1, it work, I obtain the result in the entry but when I write 1+1.0 or 1.0+1.0 then it wrash

Comment: I have a button for each number and one for the multiplication, division, minus, plus, point for the float and one for clear the entry

Comment: What exception do you get when the code crashes?

Comment: I got nothing I just begin to use monodevelop so even if i have some I don't know where there are.